# Roku sometime changes the color of static images

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am working on Roku application and sending static images to Roku for display of weather info.

**Code:**

```
If this.content.WeatherImagePath <> Invalid
    this.bitmaps[this.content.WeatherImagePath] = {
        request: Invalid,
        tries: 1,
        bitmap: CreateObject("roBitmap", this.content.WeatherImagePath),
        done: True
    }
End If
```

I am using this images to display:

[image]

But I get different response on different time
like:

[image]

And sometime there is no issue in display of images.
Like:

[image]

Memory details of device are below:

```
Available memory 14927808 used 24072192 max 39000000
```

What can be issue?

Comment: for posterity, there is an ongoing discussion on this at https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=99713

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not an issue on BrightSCript code.

It was ROKU firmware issue and on next firmware version this issue was resolved.